# Android 4.4 Webview Uncaught ReferenceError: Map is not defined. How to config Babel on vue cli to support Chrome 30 and above?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, android-webview, babeljs, vue-cli-3

I wonder how to config .browserslistrc and babel.config.js in VueJs(vue-cli-3) to support Android WebView Chrome v.30?

Current config 
 - babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
     '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
  ],
}
```

- .browserslistrc

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
```

Current error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: Map is not defined"

P.s. Tried to set .browserslistrc

```
cover 100%
```

But error still exists